# What is the differences in nuances between とうとう and やっと?

Tags: nuances, words

What is the differences in nuances between とうとう and やっと?

is it true that やっと has a more "happy" feeling attached to it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

やっと means that something realizes after spending/waiting a long time for it or making a lot of effort for it.  Therefore it is understandable that やっと has a happy feeling attached to it.  If I understand English correctly, “at last” has a similar meaning.

とうとう means that something happens as a final outcome, and what happens can be either a good thing or a bad thing.

For example, suppose that some company has been financially in a trouble for a while.  Today you heard that the company went bankrupt.

> あの会社、とうとう倒産したそうだよ。 (あのかいしゃ、とうとうとうさんしたそうだよ。)  I heard the company finally went bankrupt.

is a usual sentence.  If you say

> あの会社、やっと倒産したそうだよ。 (あのかいしゃ、やっととうさんしたそうだよ。)  I heard the company went bankrupt at last.

that means that you were waiting for the bankruptcy of the company.

Comment: You are accurate in mentioning that the effort is not a necessity. But it does not necessarily have to end up with happyness. It is just that there was expectation.

Comment: @sawa: I first thought so, too, but I find it difficult to imagine a situation where a speaker uses やっと and does not feel happy about what happened.  I think that using やっと implies that the speaker considers the event as some kind of accomplishment, and that is why it is difficult to imagine using やっと without feeling happy.

Comment: `やっと校長の話が終わった。でも、まだこれから教頭の挨拶があるんだ。`

Comment: @sawa: In that case, the speaker feels happy about the fact that 校長の話が終わった, although he/she is not entirely happy because of another factor.

Comment: You become **comparably** more happy than before, but happy.

Comment: “You become **comparably** more happy than before”  Yeah.  Is it incorrect to say “やっと has a happy feeling attached to it”?  I did not say that a speaker who uses やっと is necessarily happy.

Comment: What about いよいよ??

Comment: wow nice find!
 i want to put that in but i think i can't edit the question now.. perhaps we open a new question?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi i think the mapping to "at last" is nice =D

Answer (score 0):

> Toto  is crucially different from yatto in that the former often
>   indicates a negative situation that came about spontaneously, but the
>   latter indicates a positive situation that has been realized with the
>   greatest efforts.
>   {From intermediate dictionary on Japanese grammar pg 530}

so it seems you are right that yatto is for happier occasions.

Comment: I do not think that とうとう indicates a negative situation.  On the other hand, やっと is used for an anticipated event, and therefore I think that it is correct to say that やっと indicates a positive situation.